# rEFIt menu not identifying os

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, refit, refind

I tried to set up a tri-boot system for my mac(OSX, Ubuntu 14.04, Windows 8.1), but rEFIt is unable to identify Ubuntu and shows unknown os icon instead. It also shows multiple icons for Ubuntu and Windows. Heres what partition inspector says

```
*** Report for internal hard disk ***

Current GPT partition table:
 #      Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1             40       409639  EFI System (FAT)
 2         409640    399984823  Mac OS X HFS+
 3      399984824    401254359  Mac OS X Boot
 4      401254400    401516543  MS Reserved
 5      401516544    460109823  Basic Data
 6      460110248    489407119  Unknown
 7      489669264    490234711  Linux Swap

Current MBR partition table:
 # A    Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1              1       409639  ee  EFI Protective
 2 *       409640    399984823  af  Mac OS X HFS+
 3      399984824    401254359  af  Mac OS X HFS+
 4      401254400    401516543  da  Unknown

MBR contents:
 Boot Code: Unknown, but bootable

Partition at LBA 40:
 Boot Code: None (Non-system disk message)
 File System: FAT32
 Listed in GPT as partition 1, type EFI System (FAT)

Partition at LBA 409640:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: HFS Extended (HFS+)
 Listed in GPT as partition 2, type Mac OS X HFS+
 Listed in MBR as partition 2, type af  Mac OS X HFS+, active

Partition at LBA 399984824:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: HFS Extended (HFS+)
 Listed in GPT as partition 3, type Mac OS X Boot
 Listed in MBR as partition 3, type af  Mac OS X HFS+

Partition at LBA 401254400:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: Unknown
 Listed in GPT as partition 4, type MS Reserved
 Listed in MBR as partition 4, type da  Unknown

Partition at LBA 401516544:
 Boot Code: Windows BOOTMGR (Vista)
 File System: NTFS
 Listed in GPT as partition 5, type Basic Data

Partition at LBA 460110248:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: ext4
 Listed in GPT as partition 6, type Unknown

Partition at LBA 489669264:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: Unknown
 Listed in GPT as partition 7, type Linux Swap
```

Answer (score 0):

rEFIt is no longer being developed. Try installing my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) instead; it's based on rEFIt, but is under active development. Install it in OS X, and either use the `--alldrivers` option to `install.sh` or manually install the EFI filesystem driver for whatever filesystem you use for Ubuntu (ext4fs by default). (Manually installing a filesystem driver involves copying one file; see the [drivers documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html) for details.) If all goes well, you should be able to boot Ubuntu from rEFInd, although you may end up with extra boot options you'll want to delete from the menu.

Windows is another matter. I'd be shocked if it can boot as it is now. To get it booting, you'll need to either replace your [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) with a conventional protective MBR and do an EFI-mode installation of Windows, or edit your hybrid MBR so that it includes your Windows partition (#5). The first is a cleaner solution, but isn't guaranteed to work. The second solution is more conventional (on a Mac), but it perpetuates the use of a hybrid MBR, which is an ugly and dangerous hack.